Could not load file or assembly 'Azure.Core, version=1.40.0.0'
I have a problem where during runtime, my application get the exception:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Azure.Core, Version=1.40.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified.'

The funny thing is, that the nuget package I have installed is Version 1.41.0.0.
I cannot seem to find anywhere that it reference to version 1.40.0.0.
I also checked my output folder to see the version of Azure.Core and that is correctly 1.41.0.0
I can see in the app.config that I have a bindingRedirect:
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Azure.Core" publicKeyToken="92742159e12e44c8" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.41.0.0" newVersion="1.41.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>

I am scratching my head as to why this is happening?
EDIT:
After setting my MSBuild to Diagnostic, it reads out the following:
   Unified primary reference "Azure.Core, Version=1.41.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8". (TaskId:21)
1>      Using this version instead of original version "1.40.0.0" in "C:\Users\user\.nuget\packages\azure.identity\1.12.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Azure.Identity.dll" because AutoUnify is 'true'. (TaskId:21)
1>      Using this version instead of original version "1.37.0.0" in "C:\Users\user\.nuget\packages\azure.security.keyvault.secrets\4.6.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets.dll" because AutoUnify is 'true'. (TaskId:21)
1>      Resolved file path is "C:\Users\user\.nuget\packages\azure.core\1.41.0\lib\net472\Azure.Core.dll". (TaskId:21)
1>      Reference found at search path location "{RawFileName}". (TaskId:21)
1>      Found related file "C:\Users\user\.nuget\packages\azure.core\1.41.0\lib\net472\Azure.Core.xml". (TaskId:21)
1>      This reference is not "CopyLocal" because at least one source item had "Private" set to "false" and no source items had "Private" set to "true". (TaskId:21)


Do you use any other assembly besides Azure.Core? If so, there might be one that uses Azure.Core as transitive dependency, which could be an older/newer version of Azure.Core. The issue occurs during runtime as there might be racing condition that the other ("wrong") version of the assembly is loaded first.

I do have other assemblies, like Azure.Identity and Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets.
If what you say about it being a racing condition, how do I "counter" that?

Based on your comment it looks like you have an issue with transitive packages.
The packages Azure.Identity and Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets both need the Azore.Core package. As I do not have a full overview of your project setup, the following solutions might or might not work, dependent on your project structure.
1.) Remove your reference to Azure.Core
As the other assemblies already refer Azure.Core, Azure.Core should still be referable for you, even when you do not have a direct dependency to it. That might solve the issue already, but as both packages (Azure.Identity and Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets) refer Azure.Core, they both might also refer two different versions. In this case, you need to change the versions of those packages until you find matching Azure.Core versions.
2.) Update your direct Azure.Core reference to a corresponding version
In case you still need/want the direct reference, make sure your referenced version fits to the version the other packages refer to.
For example:
Azure.Identity V1.12.0 -> Requires Azure.Core >= V1.25.0
Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets V4.4.0 -> Requires Azure.Core >= V1.25.0
Direct reference Azure.Core V1.20.0 -> Upgrade to V1.25.0
(those are really just examples, in reality its more likely that the packages often require different versions, so this is really a happy case)

Sorry for the late response - I have been busy trying to figure it out. So I do need the reference to the Azure.Core, because both my Libraries uses it. I put the MSBuild to "Diagnostic", to see what is actually being loaded. It refers to Azure.Core 1.41.0 like it should a lot of times, except for a few lines (see edit). But it says which are using the 1.40.0 and 1.37.0, but it also says that it is using the 1.41 instead of those.
